# How can I get the context in a module that has no visibility with the Application class?

Tags: java, android

I need to access a method through the context, but I have no way to access it because the module in which this method is located, has no visibility with the app module and I can't give it to it because it would cause circular dependency error:

```java
private static synchronized String createDataPath(String path) {
    File fileDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(path);
    if (fileDir != null) {
        return fileDir.getAbsolutePath();

    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Before I used to get that context by storing the context in a static variable, but this causes a memory leak and I have already seen that it is not recommended to do it this way at all.

When I have had context problems I used to access the instance of the Application class that provided me with a context, but in this case I cannot access the Application class because it is not in my module.

The other option is to pass the context by method parameter but it is a project with hundreds of classes and methods, so passing the context by parameter would make me have to pass the context to all the methods that depend on it, thus creating a gigantic pyramid, and that is what I am trying to avoid, what other option do I have?

Comment: Pass it in as a parameter to the function.  If necessary, chain this several times.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your project structure looks like this:

```
app module (depend upon these modules as below) 
    --- module A 
    --- module B 
    ......
```

Seems that there is no Fragment / Activity in your module x after I read your description.

If I am not mistaken, in this case, you should pass the context in as a parameter.

In our business project, we also use many modules, some of them haven't any Activity/Fragment but we used **DI(e.g dagger)**, to pass the context as a parameter in the constructor method in those modules.